# War on the moon between two nations, one of which votes on strategy and one which does not

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, military-sf

This [thread](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/264879/can-someone-explain-military-democracy-as-referenced-in-deaths-end) reminded me of a story I read in *Analog* in the post-2000 era, about a war on the moon (I'm pretty sure) between two nations, one of which decided strategies via public vote, and one of which had the authoritarian ruler decide such matters.

Probably based loosely on the Peloponnesian War

Answer (score 2):

This is reminiscent of Herman Wouk's brief novel, [*The "Lomokome" Papers*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?22999) (1968), in which an American astronaut is captured on the Moon and learns about their society, particularly how they avoid nuclear war. In the nation of Lomokome, the wise rule in a committee of 59 men, who elect one of their members as the head, and select a replacement when one dies. In the rival nation of Lomadine, representatives are chosen by lot from the adult population, and the president is chosen by lot from the representatives. The two lunar nations avoid a nuclear disaster by staging virtual wars, submitting strategies to a neutral War College, which assigns them tasks such as competing to produce niobium or material goods. The martial spirit benefits society and many young men volunteer, yet no weapons are fired. At the end of the conflict, the War College

> informs the nations which one has lost, and requires the leaders to personally slit the throats of some thousands of young men.

This keeps war from being declared too often despite its stimulating nature.

But so far as I know this was never published in *Analog*.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm almost positive it's not what I'm looking for but it's an interesting example of the same theme